# How can i calculate the distance from the top of pictureBox1 and almost the top of form1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a label with text inside i can change the label size or the label font size each time and check many times but maybe there is a way to calculate it:

```
label18.Text = "מכם מזג האוויר איננו פעיל כרגע";
```

This is how i see the text now:

[image: Text]

The text in red is in hebrew this is the text i want to change it's size and also to put it in the middle according to the picturebox1 top not on the left like it is now.

And i did a black circle just to show what i mean by " the distance from the top of pictureBox1 and almost the top of form1 ".
I mean this gray area from the above the pictureBox1 and the form1 white area on the top only this gray area i want to make the text in this height and in the middle.
How can i calculate this two values ?

I tried this but it's not in the exact middle:

[image: Not middle]

```
SizeF size = label18.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(label18.Text, label18.Font);
label18.Left = (pictureBox1.Width / 2) - (((int)size.Width) / 2) + pictureBox1.Left;
label18.Top = pictureBox1.Top - 20;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need graphics or to measure anything. Just set in designer `text align = middlecenter` and `autosize = true`

```
label18.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + (pictureBox1.Width / 2 - label18.Width / 2, 
                             pictureBox1.Location.Y - label18.Height);
```

Comment: Tried it not working. In all answers it's not in the middle and when i set the label property auto size to false then it's in the middle but then the text is inside it's not spread i mean you don't see all the text only the first word. But then it's in the middle.

Comment: @JamesAharon It works. Just set autosize to true to fit the text!

Comment: You can't make label18.Location.X = you get: Error 32 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable So maybe i need to use new Point(.... ?

Comment: @JamesAharon Yes you are right. I dont have visual studio to test it. See edit

Answer (score 2):

To center a label you need it get it actual size, then to center it using another control use some simple math to get the coordinate for the control (see below Example 1). I don't know what control the grey bar is but you could center in that by using the size.Width property and doing the same type of calculation.

If you want to fill the grey bar I have added Example 2.

**Example 1:**

```
private void CenterLabel()
{
    //get the size of the text (you could do this before hand if needed)
    SizeF size = label18.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(label18.Text, label18.Font);

    //center over picture box control and slightly above
    label18.Left = (pictureBox1.Width / 2) - (((int)size.Width) / 2)  + pictureBox1.Left;
    label18.Top = pictureBox1.Top - 20;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
private void CenterLabel()
{
    int fontHeightPixels = (int)(greyBar.Height * .85);
    Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", fontHeightPixels, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    string text = "I am centered";

    //get the size of the text (you could do this before hand if needed)
    SizeF size = label18.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(text, font);

    label18.Font = font;
    label18.Text = text;

    //center over picture box control and slightly above
    label18.Left = (pictureBox1.Width / 2) - (((int)size.Width) / 2) + pictureBox1.Left;
    label18.Top = (greyBar.Height / 2) - (((int)size.Height) / 2) + greyBar.Top;            
}
```

Comment: Kevin close there mut be a way to calculate the it so each time i change the size of the text it will be in the middle. Even if i'm not changing the text size. It's close. ( updated my question with image of your solution ).

Comment: Kevin you forgot to add the greyBar variable. I don't have any greyBar variable.

Comment: Did you add the  + pictureBox1.Left; to the calculation? Also the other suggestions below sound reasonable if this doesn't work.

Comment: Not seeing you form and how the grey bar is implemented I made some example code. You would have to adjust based on how you implemented the form.

Comment: Kevin ok my mistake now i see the grey part is a menuStrip i added to my form in the designer. So the grey part is the distance between the top of the pictureBox1 and the menuStrip1.

Comment: Sounds like the other answer worked best for you. This works on my form design, I just don't know quite enough about yours :)

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple with Windows forms:

1. Dock your label to the top of the form by setting the appropriate property in the Forms designer. The property you want to set is `Dock` and it should be set to `Top`.
2. Change the label's `AutoSize` property to `false`.
3. Change the label's height as desired.
4. Change the label's `TextAlign` property to `MiddleCentre`.

That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

There's more then one way to achieve this goal.

I would suggest the following:

1. First calculate the width of the picturebox (picturebox.Width)
2. Find the coordinates on the form where the picturebox resides (picturebox.Location) property of the picturebox)
3. Then you change the location of your label control --> to Label.Location.X = (picturebox.Width /2) and Label.Location.Y = picturebox.Location.Y  ==> now you have the label correctly placed .

   4. Next Set the Height of the Label Control to the Top(distance between the edge of the form and picturebox) value of the Picturebox.

No visual studion from where i am typing so cannot do full code example.

You're done.